# How to customise alert events in Firebase Crashlytics

Tags: firebase, crashlytics, alerts, customizing

We are trying to set up Crashlytics Incident management and alerting them using Opsgenie.

There are only standard issues are allowed for alerts in Firebase Crashlytics like

ANR for First
[image]

I would like to have customised events to have alerts

E.g Any ANR with certain number of occurrences (say 20k), Any Crash that happens for 10% users etc

Kindly help me out the ways to customise the events with different conditions and create alerts for them

The straight forward events are already working fine. I searched for configuring such events but not able to find ways